# DLL export issues with PAnsiChar in Delphi XE7 using stdcall convention

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, dllexport

I have a DLL- which has a function

```
Decrypt(aText, aKey: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar; stdcall
```

and this function has been exported.
as

```
exports
  Decrypt;
```

And If I call from client in below way:

```
lH :=  LoadLibrary('EncDec.dll');
FEncDyc := GetProcAddress(lH , PChar('Decrypt'));

lResult := FEncDyc(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(EditPwd.Text)), 
    PAnsiChar(AnsiString(EditKey.Text)));
```

where `FEncDyc` is a pointer to func of type

```
TDecrypt =  function (aText: PAnsiChar; aKey: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
```

I always get Junk values for parameters aText and aKey; where am I going wrong?
if I change the definition of dll to

```
Decrypt(aText, aKey: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar; export;
```

I get values in the DLL with no junk characters- works fine!

Whats wrong in the code for an stdcall and what does it make difference if I use export key instead.

Also please suggest: Whats the right way to pass PAnsiChar and how to typecast it to AnsiString in my dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to specify the calling convention when importing. Instead of

```
TDecrypt = function(aText: PAnsiChar; aKey: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
```

you need

```
TDecrypt = function(aText: PAnsiChar; aKey: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar; stdcall;
```

Do be careful with the return value. You have to ensure that the value that you return is allocated dynamically using `GetMem` or equivalent. And you also need to export a deallocator from the DLL.

Comment: If I need to pass a value of type PansiChar - Is this the right way?

Comment: Your passing is fine. Conversion to AnsiString, then cast to PAnsiChar, that's fine.